# Matrix valued function with low-rank input matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Consider functions as $f:\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. I am trying to find examples of these functions that are cheaper to evaluate (numerically) on low-rank matrices (for which the SVD is known) than on full-rank ones.

Can you suggest some examples?

More precisely, suppose that to compute $f(A)$ we need time $t$. Let $\Pi_r(A) = USV^T$ be the rank $r$ truncated SVD of $A$. What has to satisfy $f$ in order to have that $f(USV^T)$ can be evaluated in a time $t'<t$ for every $A$?

Comment: Could you give some examples of the kinds of functions $f$ that you would are interested in considering?

Comment: Sure, a simple yet interesting example for me would be $f(A)=WA+B$, where $W,B$ are just constant matrices.

Comment: So that indeed is an example of such a function $f$, since we can write
$$
WA = (W(US))V^T,
$$
which reduces a $k\times m, m \times n$ product to successive $k \times m, m \times r$ and $k\times r, r\times n$ products.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! Are all the examples of functions like these based on collecting the factors in a smart way?

Comment: If a typical $O(kmn))$ algorithm is used for $k\times m,m \times n$ multiplications, then the faster version has complexity $O(kmr) + O(knr) = O(k\max\{m,n\} r)$. We should expect that this algorithm is roughly $\min\{m,n\}/(2r)$ times faster.

Comment: It's hard to say whether **every** function that can be done more quickly for low rank matrices has this form.